# SQL pass-through SAS/ SAS EG - return a table

Tags: sas, pass-through

Case:
I want to run a SQL pass-through from SAS and I want an output in my work libary.

Problem:
The log tells me everything is fine but there is no dataset output?
I am a big rookie on this area - please help.

```
Proc sql;

connect to odbc as mydb
    (dsn=x user=x password=x);


execute (  
DECLARE @return_value int 
EXEC    fpt.usp_Marcus_Buy_and_Sell_amounts
@Country ='DK',
@Date ='2016-01-01', 
@Date2='2016-02-01'  

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value 







        ) by mydb;


Quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you are only asking SAS to execute a query in the Database.
To get a table back to your SAS work library you will need to include a create table statement on the SAS side.

e.g.

```
Proc sql;

connect to odbc as mydb
    (dsn=x user=x password=x);

create table mydb_return as select * 
       from connection to mydb
         ( EXEC fpt.usp_Marcus_Buy_and_Sell_amounts
            @Country ='DK',
            @Date ='2016-01-01', 
            @Date2='2016-02-01' 
         );

disconnect from mydb;

Quit;
```

edit: changed statement according to the comments

Comment: When I run your code the log says:
ERROR: CLI describe error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@return_value". : 
       [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

But I just declared the variable "@Return_value"?

Comment: Ok, variables are not global. Try directly inserting the  `EXEC    fpt.usp_Marcus_Buy_and_Sell_amounts
   @Country ='DK',
   @Date ='2016-01-01', 
   @Date2='2016-02-01'` into the create table statement, without declare and select.

Answer (score 0):

Jetzler answer is great!
Though I found out I could reduce the code to just :

```
Proc sql;

connect to odbc as mydb
    (dsn=x user=x password=x);

create table mydb_return as select * 
       from connection to mydb
         (EXEC    fpt.usp_Marcus_Buy_and_Sell_amounts
@Country ='DK',
@Date ='2016-01-01', 
@Date2='2016-02-01'  
 ) ;

disconnect from mydb;


Quit;
```